# Adding an SKLabelNode to Scene Kit View

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am building a game using Scene Kit. In order to present the score I wanted to use an SKLabelNode on the screen, however, when I attach it to a SCNNode, it looks very blurry: [image]

Here is the code that I have written to do this, please let me know if there is a better way to go about doing this without having the text be so blurry. Thank you so much!

```
func initHUD() {

    let skScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    skScene.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)

    labelNode = SKLabelNode()
    labelNode.fontSize = 20
    labelNode.position.y = 50
    labelNode.position.x = 50

    skScene.addChild(labelNode)

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.lightingModelName = SCNLightingModelConstant
    material.doubleSided = true
    material.diffuse.contents = skScene
    plane.materials = [material]

    hudNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    hudNode.name = "HUD"
    hudNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 3.14159265)
    hudNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y: 1, z: -5)
}

func updateHUD() {
    labelNode.text = "\(score)"
}
```

Comment: Attach SKLabelNode to SCNNode?  Where do you do it?  Besides, what hudNode and what does it have to do with SKLabelNode?

Comment: Label node is a child of skScene which is attached to the HUDNode by means of a plane that skScene acts as a material

Comment: I don't see in your code how the label node in question is related to hudNode.

Comment: The HUDNode acts as a 2D plane in SceneKit to show the label, for some reason it is really blurry. IS there a way not to have to attach the SKLabel to a SceneKit Node?

Comment: I suggest you restate the 2nd sentence from the top if you don't mean it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical way to do a HUD for a SceneKit scene is to create a SpriteKit `SKScene` and set it as the `overlaySKScene` of your SceneKit view. Then it renders at full resolution and always at the same view-relative size and position.

Comment: can u write the code down here. I don't understand this